# Finding the Intersection of 2 sorted lists

Tags: java, linked-list, set-intersection

I have an assignment for 
Given two sorted lists of comparable items, 
L1 and L2. You can assume that in L1 and 
L2 all elements are different (no duplicates) but t
he interception between L1 and L2 may be 
non-empty.

(b)
Implement  an  efficient  method  in 
Java to  compute  the symmetric  difference(∆) 
between  L1  and  L2,  L1 ∆L2.  Please  remember  that  in 
set  theory,  the symmetric 
difference of two sets A and B is the set of elements either in A or in B but not in both. 
Example: Suppose A = {1,3,5,7,9} and B = {1,2,3,4,5}, A ∆ B = {2,4,7,9}.

I wrote this so far but I don't know why it stops the search at the end of the first list and doesn't continue checking the 2nd list for differences. Any help?

```
    public static <AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
        void symDifference(List<AnyType> L1, List<AnyType> L2,
                List<AnyType> Difference) 
{

    ListIterator<AnyType> iterL1 = L1.listIterator();
    ListIterator<AnyType> iterL2 = L2.listIterator();
    AnyType itemL1 = null;
    AnyType itemL2 = null;

    if (iterL1.hasNext() && iterL2.hasNext()) 
    {
        itemL1 = iterL1.next();
        itemL2 = iterL2.next();
    }

    while (itemL1 != null && itemL2 != null) 
    {
        int compareResult = itemL1.compareTo(itemL2);
        if (compareResult == 0) 
        {
            itemL1 = iterL1.hasNext() ? iterL1.next() : null;
            itemL2 = iterL2.hasNext() ? iterL2.next() : null;
        } 
        else if (compareResult < 0) 
        {
            Difference.add(itemL1);
            itemL1 = iterL1.hasNext() ? iterL1.next() : null;
        } 
        else
        {
            Difference.add(itemL2);
            itemL2 = iterL2.hasNext() ? iterL2.next() : null;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LinkedList<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> difList = new LinkedList<>();

    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(3);
    list1.add(5);
    list1.add(7);
    list1.add(9);

    list2.add(1);
    list2.add(2);
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(4);
    list2.add(5);

    symDifference(list1,list2,difList);
    System.out.println(difList);

}
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: You said to loop `while (itemL1 != null && itemL2 != null)`. Why would you expect it to do something else?

Comment: It’s a classic pitfall. When one list runs dry, your loop stops (as it should). At this point you will still want to exhaust the other list. Hint: Since you know one list is done and only one has elements remaining, but you don’t know which, the easy solution is just to take all remaining elements from both lists.

Comment: @OleV.V alright but how would i get the remaining elements from the longer list without duplicating and adding to the time complexity?

Comment: Since the lists are sorted and one list has run dry, you know that the remainder of the other list cannot contain any elements from the run-dry list, so you simply take them all.

Comment: @OleV.V. But wouldnt that mean creating another loop inside the while loop which would change the time complexity?

Comment: No, after the while loop (so your time complexity will not get hurt).

Comment: Oh alright, yea I got it by adding two while loops after for list 1 and then list 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, think about this. 
list1 {1, 2, 3, 5}
list2 {1, 5}.
As shmosel said, what happen if your loop runs twice? It exit the loop, and the function. 
Ideally, you want to go through all elements on **both array**.

BTW,  I don't think your solution is working as well (you can of cause, but your code will look super ugly, probably takes O(list1.length * list2.length)). Since both lists are sorted, you can compare both element, and loop the smaller element list first. For example, using list1 and list2, compare 1 and 1, both equal, then move to 2 and 5. Then compare 2 and 5, add 2 to the list, and move 2 to 3 **ONLY**. Which takes O(list1.length + list2.length).

Comment: But what if you don't know which one is larger or smaller? All i know is that its sorted but the lists can be whatever length.

Comment: You don't need to know. All you need is: compare list1 item with list 2 item. If they are equal, list1Item = list1.next(); list2Item = list2.next(); If list1 item is bigger, list2Item = list2.next(), and similar if list2 item is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a classic pitfall. When one list runs dry, your loop stops (as it should). At this point you will still want to exhaust the other list. So after your while loop insert the logic to copy the remaining elements from the other list. Since you know one list is done and only one has elements remaining, but you don’t know which, the easy solution is just to take the remaining elements from both lists. Since both lists were sorted, you know that the remainder of the list that still has elements in it cannot contain any elements from the run-dry list, so you simply add them all to your result. All in all you will probably add two while loops after the loop you have, one for `iterL1` and one for `iterL2`. Since each of these run in linear time, your time complexity will not get hurt.